Independence of two systems
This is probably a very noob question, but I've just started learning about quantum computing.
In IBM's lesson on multiple systems they say that two classical systems $X$ and $Y$ with classical state sets $\Sigma$ and $\Gamma$ respectively are independent if
$$\text{Pr}((X, Y) = (a, b)) = \text{Pr}(X=a)\text{Pr}(Y=b),$$
for every $a \in \Sigma$ and $b \in \Gamma$.
This makes sense to me because it's just like independence for random variables, but then they make the following statement:

To express this condition in terms of probability vectors, assume that the given probabilistic state of
$(X,Y)$ is described by a probability vector, written in the Dirac notation as $$\sum_{(a, b) \in \Sigma \times \Gamma}p_{ab} |ab \rangle.$$ The condition for independence if then equivalent to the existence of two probability vectors $$|\phi \rangle = \sum_{a \in \Sigma}q_a|a\rangle \text{  and  } |\psi\rangle = \sum_{b \in \Gamma}r_b|b \rangle$$ representing the probabilities associated with the classical states of
$X$ and $Y$, respectively, such that $$p_{ab} = q_ar_b.$$

I don't understand why this condition is equivalent to independence defined previously. The quoted statement seems to disregard what the states of $X$ and $Y$ really are.
So, for example, you could say that if the state of a pair of bits is given by
$$\frac{1}{6}|00\rangle + \frac{1}{12}|01\rangle+\frac{1}{2}|10\rangle + \frac{1}{4}|11\rangle,$$
then the two bits are independent because the condition is satisfied by vectors $$|\phi \rangle = \frac{1}{4}|0\rangle + \frac{3}{4}|1\rangle \text{  and  } |\psi\rangle = \frac{2}{3}|0\rangle + \frac{1}{3}|1\rangle,$$
but what if the state of the first and second bit was $|0\rangle$, for example? Then they wouldn't be independent according to the definition, would they?

Can you state your supposed counterexample at the end a bit more explicitly please?
The relation to the previous independent relation is q_a = p(X=a) and r_b = P(Y=b). We obtain this since P(X=a) = \sum_b P(X=a, Y=b) = \sum_b q_a r_b  = q_a \sum_b r_b = q_a. Going the otherway is pretty much be definition.

if the state of the first and second qubit is $|0\rangle$ then the state is $|0\rangle\otimes|0\rangle$, corresponding to the joint probability distribution with $p_{00}=1$ and $p_{ij}=0,i,j>0$, which clearly factorises.

Let's start with a simple biased coin example. Using the probability vector notation, we can write
$$|\psi\rangle = p |H\rangle + (1-p)|T\rangle.$$
This means the probability of the event $H$ is $p$, and the probability of the event $T$  is $1-p$. Equivalently, we could also express that as $P(H) = p$ and $P(T)=1-p$.
Now, consider flipping two biased coins. These two systems (coins) are independent. Our sample space is $HH, HT, TH, TT$. The joint distribution can be described by the probability vector
$$|\Phi\rangle = pq|HH\rangle + p(1-q)|HT\rangle + (1-p)q|TH\rangle + (1-p)(1-q)|TT\rangle,$$
where $q$ is the probability of the event $H$ for the second coin. In other words, we have $P(HH)=pq, P(HT)=p(1-q)$ and so on.
Because systems are independent, their joint distribution can be factored. This is equivalent to factoring the probability vector like so:
$$|\Phi\rangle = (p|H\rangle + (1-p)|T\rangle)(q|H\rangle + (1-q)|T\rangle)$$
Clearly, we just found two probability vectors
$$|\psi\rangle = p |H\rangle + (1-p)|T\rangle$$
and
$$|\phi\rangle = q |H\rangle + (1-q)|T\rangle$$
such that
$$|\Phi\rangle = |\psi\rangle |\phi\rangle.$$
Conversely, we have two dependent systems whenever we can't factor the probability vector $|\Phi\rangle$.
Also, we should remember that the probabilities must sum up to 1. Indeed, for the example above, we have
$$pq + p(1-q) + (1-p)q + (1-p)(1-q) = 1.$$

More generally, suppose we have an arbitrary vector
$$|\Phi\rangle = a|HH\rangle + b|HT\rangle + c|TH\rangle + d|TT\rangle.$$
We want to know if we can factor it (two systems are independent). Then, we can simply compute the determinant of the matrix
\begin{align}
M=\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
If $\det(M)=0$, then the matrix is at most rank 1. This means that we can express $M$ as an outer product of two vectors
$$M = |\psi\rangle \langle \phi|.$$
If we translate that back to the vector notation, then we get
$$|\Phi\rangle = |\psi\rangle |\phi\rangle.$$
Therefore, $\det(M)=0$ if and only if $|\Phi\rangle = |\psi\rangle |\phi\rangle$.

In the biased coin example, the matrix is
\begin{align}
M=\begin{pmatrix}
pq & p(1-q)\\
(1-p)q & (1-p)(1-q)
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
It is not hard to see that $\det(M)=0$, and we can express $M$ as
$$
M =
\begin{pmatrix}
p\\
1-p
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
q & 1-q
\end{pmatrix} = |\psi\rangle \langle \phi|.
$$
We have seen that $|\Phi\rangle = |\psi\rangle |\phi\rangle$. Two systems are independent.

Thanks for an insightful answer! So if my understanding is correct, for showing independence it's not enough to show that the state vector of the compound state can be factored; the state vectors that it factors into have to be the state vectors of the constituent parts of the system. To make it concrete, factoring the state in my question into $(1/6|0\rangle+1/2|1\rangle) \otimes (1|0\rangle + 1/2|1\rangle)$ doesn't show anything.

Probabilities should add up to 1. In your example, these vectors are not quantum states nor probability vectors. I suggest you read the Wikipedia article about independence https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)
